# How to activate component only when data comes from server?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

There is a parent component where I call its child component:

```
 <app-add-object-layer-component></app-add-object-layer-component>
```

Child has a service inside:

```
 constructor(private editService: editService) {

 }

 getEditData(){
    return this.editService.get();
 }
```

Child component is initialised always even there is no data returned.

Sure, I can move `editService` upper and use it like:

```
<app-add-object-layer-component *ngIf="editService.getEditData()"></app-add-object-layer-component>
```

But in this case parent component has alien dependency `constructor(private editService: editService) {}`

How to show/hide child component in parent component according to data returned by getEditData method?

Comment: where is your getEditData method declared in child or parent?

Comment: That is question, I dont know where to do that better, isolated in child or in parent

Comment: I dont want that parent depends from ` editService` because it needed only for child component

Comment: handle this scenario with event emitter

Comment: What does your getEditData do and  what your child component does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is wrong. **editService.getEditData()** will return promise. Which is defined and true always. You need to check resolved value. For that use async pipe.

> "(editService.getEditData() **| async**)?.something"

more: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/

```
<app-add-object-layer-component *ngIf="(editService.getEditData() | async)?.something"></app-add-object-layer-component>
```

Answer (score -1):

declare the component variable `data:any;`
Then in `ngOnInit() {}` get this data from server using your service function like `this.editService.getEditData.subscribe(res=> this.data = res)`

then in html you use it like `<app-add-object-layer-component *ngIf="data"></app-add-object-layer-component>`

Comment: So, do you recomment to move service from child to parent? By is comes to mess, because parent has service that needs only for child.